# Stuck at Actionbar android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm an Android beginner and working on project with the `ActionBar`, but I'm stuck. The menu is not coming to the `ActionBar`.

**activity_main_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search / will display always -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Location Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
      android:title="@string/action_location_found"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Refresh -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_refresh"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
      android:title="@string/action_help"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Check updates -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>'


</resources>'
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following namespace in your activity_main_actions.xml

```
                xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And replace

```
           android:showAsAction
```

With

```
           yourapp:showAsAction
```

Now your final code will be like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
  <!-- Search / will display always -->
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="@string/action_search"
  yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

  <!-- Location Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
  android:title="@string/action_location_found"
   yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <!-- Refresh -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
  android:title="@string/action_refresh"
   yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

     <!-- Help -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
  android:title="@string/action_help"
   yourapp:showAsAction="never"/>

  <!-- Check updates -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
  android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
   yourapp:showAsAction="never" />
   </menu>
    </resources>
```

And Let me know if problem exists

Comment: But only search and location icon is coming rest of the three item are not coming.

Comment: change always or ifRoom in "yourapp:showAsAction="never"